# Permissions-Policy: autoplay=* just does not work

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, policy, autoplay

I need to play a sound as part of a notification even when the user has not interacted with the page or the site. When reading the documentation I noticed that sending a response header as permissions-policy: autoplay=* will allow the autoplay to work but no, it is not working...

any help on this will be appreciated

What can I do to allow playing a sound if needed even when the user has not click, scroll or have done any gesture?

In my use case, the user is taking to a pretty much static Dashboard after Azure AD OAuth success login redirects him to it